# How does a nuclear reactor initiate nuclear fission?

Tags: nuclear-technology, nuclear-engineering

How do we start a nuclear chain reaction? For example, if we wanted to do it this weekend, what would we need, and what are the basic steps? I'm not looking for a text book response or highly detailed information. I'm only curious about the most basic components. For example, we need to take A and B and submerge it into C? That's all I'm asking. If you had a daughter, and she asked, "What happens in a nuclear power plant?", what would you tell her?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering.  Your question is much too broad as whole text books have been written on the matter.  Please focus your question to a specific issue or question that is answerable within the StackExchange Q&A format.

Comment: I simplified the question. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry for the late react. I think you wanted to ask: "how does a nuclear reactor initiate the *chain reaction*"? The answer is in this case, that also this is spontaneous, because even a single neutron would be enough (but there is more due to the spontaneous reactions in the fuel).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nuclear fission is spontaneous. In fact, if you have a critical mass of fuel assembled, you need to take explicit steps to keep it from going into chain reaction, typically by adding neutron-absorbing material, AKA "control rods" to the assembly. When you remove the control rods, the reactor starts up by itself.

Comment: So, it sounds like it is a only matter of placing the right materials in the right place at the right time.

Comment: Uranium 235 decays alpha. I suppose it is the first alpha particles that start the reaction by splitting another uranium atom, right?